# Preserve history of file from before it was moved into the directory being split

Tags: git, git-subtree

Suppose I have a git repo containing a file `text.txt` inside a directory `dir_a`. Later on, I decide to move `text.txt` to a new directory called `dir_b`.

After a while, I decide I should split `dir_b` into its own standalone git repository using `git subtree split`. By default, the earliest commit in `dir_b`'s repository is the commit where I moved `text.txt` from `dir_a` to `dir_b`, which is unfortunate, because e.g. a blame won't work as intended.

Is there a way to preserve, in the new git repo, the changes made to `text.txt` when it was still in `dir_a`?

To make it clear, in the original repository, the commit where I move `text.txt` from `dir_a` to `dir_b` successfully registers the move operation as a rename, so e.g. `git diff` works properly there. My problem is that, in *the new repository*, the commits made before the move aren't carried over to the new repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I quite missed the `git subtree split -P prefix` part of this.  The original answer still applies, but with a possibly-fatal twist.

When you run `git subtree split -P prefix [ options ] [ commit-range ]`, you are telling Git to *copy* some commits to new ones.  You have Git copy whatever commits contain any files within the given *`prefix`*, but with these changes:

1. Discard all files that *don't* begin with the given *`prefix`*.
2. Rename the remaining files to strip *`prefix`* (and a slash) off.
3. If the commit matches the previously-copied commit, drop it entirely.

(You could do this with `git filter-branch` as well, although it would be slower than `git subtree split`, and it requires that you first create a new branch to filter.)

The result is a new, disjoint commit graph (or subgraph since it's now added to your main commit graph), rooted at the first-copied commit and terminating at the last-copied one.  (The copy process has to enumerate commits, in Git's usual backwards fashion, from a single tip commit, not from multiple tip commits.  Once all commits have been found this way, the copying goes from root / last-enumerated, to tip, as it must.)  You can then give this new sub-graph a branch name using `git subtree`'s `-b branch` option.  If you don't give it a name, you have a short period (14 days by default) during which you can do something with the tip commit hash ID that `git subtree split` prints, and after that the copies are eligible for automatic garbage-collection.

As a brief illustration, consider the following graph:

```
     C--D--E
    /       \
A--B         H--I--J--K   <-- master
    \       /
     F-----G
```

Let's say commit `A` has in a `README` (and nothing else), `B` adds the first part of the project, `C-D-E` is more of the project, `F` and `G` were from a feature branch and add a subtree named `subbie` containing various files, `H` merges the subtree, in `I` it's renamed `feature`, in `J` nothing happens to it, and in `K` `feature/README_TOO` is added.

If you now *split* `feature` as a subtree, this makes Git copy commits:

- `I`: `feature` first appears as a name, containing, e.g., `feature/__init.py` and `feature/impl.py`, for instance.
- `K`: `feature/README_TOO` appears.

As a new, independent sub-graph of commits, it looks like this:

```
     C--D--E
    /       \
A--B         H--I--J--K   <-- master
    \       /
     F-----G

I'--K'                    <-- dash-b-argument
```

Note that we *did not copy* `F`, `G`, and `H`: they do not have files whose name starts with `feature/`.  Commit `J` does have such files, but they are the same as they were in commit `I`, so we skipped it.  Meanwhile, the *names* of the files in commits `I'` and `K'` are not `feature/__init__.py` and so on, but rather simply `__init__.py` and so on.

As I noted in the original answer, the history in a repository *is* the commits.  We view the history by starting from a branch tip commit and working backwards.  If we start at `K'` and work backwards to `I'`, the history is just those two commits.  To discover the rename, we would have to *also* copy commits `F` and `G` at least, and maybe `H` as well (there's nothing for `H` to merge this time as we would skip `A-B-C-D-E`, so we'd probably just drop `H` entirely).  But to do that, we would have to know to preserve `subbie/*`.

You could modify the `git subtree` code to allow additional preserved-as-as prefix arguments.  There is no clear way to reverse this after-the-fact, though.  The basic `git subtree` code relies on a unique prefix: it *was* always stripped off, so to reverse the transformation, we always add it back.  The two obvious options are: never strip any prefix (so never add anything), or require that additional, non-stripped prefixes never "collide with" prefix-stripped names.  That is, given any arbitrary copied commit, if its snapshot has a file named `pa/th/to/file.ext`, either `pa/th/to` is *not* a "preserved in place" prefix (so it gets the `-P` prefix added back), or else `pa/th/to` *is* such a prefix (so it gets nothing added).

---

#### Original answer

In Git, files don't have history.  There is nothing to preserve!

In Git, only *commits* have—or rather, *are*—history.  Each commit is a complete snapshot of a source tree, plus some meta-data: a name and email and a timestamp (as the author of the commit), another name/email/timestamp triple (for the committer); a commit log message; and—crucial for forming history—the ID of a *parent commit*.

(Some commits, which we call *merge commits*, have two or more parents.  At least one commit—namely the first ever made—has *no* parents; we call this a *root commit*.  But most commits just have one parent, which is normally the commit that was the tip of some branch, just before the committer made a *new* commit that *became* the tip of that branch.)

It's by comparing a commit against its parent that we find out what happened over time.  If the previous (parent) commit had 10 files, and the subsequent (child) commit had 11 files, then someone must have added a file.  If the child commit has a new line 20 in `README.txt`, they must have added that line.  But we only *discover* these dynamically, by comparing parent and child.  That is the history, formed by the commits.

The `git blame` code will, as it works from child back to parent (and then treating that parent as another child of *another* parent), search for lines taken from other files, or for entire files renamed from one location to another.  How *well* that search works is a separate matter—but as a general rule, if some file `p/a/t/h.ext` exists in the parent but not the child, and some other file `n/e/w.name` exists in the child but not the parent, Git will put these two files into a "candidates for rename detection" list.

If two differently-named files are absolutely, 100%, bit-for-bit identical, Git will nearly always<sup>1</sup> pair them up.  The less-identical they become, the less-likely Git will be to pair them up.  This pairing has control knobs: in `git diff` and friends, they are the `--find-renames` value.  There is also a `--find-copies` and a `--find-copies-harder`.  In `git blame`, the `-C` argument controls things, in a somewhat different way.  I have not experimented enough with this to say for sure how it works, but either one or two `-C` arguments should certainly detect a whole-file rename, based on [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html).

---

<sup>1</sup>For `git diff`, rename-finding is completely *dis*abled by default in Git versions before 2.9, but *en*abled by default in Git versions 2.9 and higher.  You can set `diff.renames` to `true` to enable it, without configuring a particular `-M` / `--find-renames` threshold, in older versions of Git.

There is also a maximum pairing-queue size, configurable as `diff.renameLimit`.  Hitting that limit is rare, although renaming every file in a directory—which is *how* Git treats renaming a directory—is more likely to be *able* to hit it.  The default limit has grown over the years; it used to be 100, then 200, and is now 400 files.

Comment: Okay, but in the original repo, moving from `dir_a` to `dir_b` is successfully registered as a rename -- that is, `dir_a/text.txt` and `dir_b/text.txt` _are_ paired up, so git _does_ see them as the same file. The problem is not in the original repository, but in the new repository created with `git subtree split`. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, right. The issue is, as you observed, that `git subtree split` itself only copies the commits that use the new paths. To preserve the other commits you would need a variant of `git subtree split` that took multiple prefixes and did not "move up" files to a new root, i.e., did not change prefix/foo/bar to foo/bar at all. (You can do this with `git filter-branch` but you lose the ability to `git subtree merge` etc.) Or, you could have a variant of `git subtree split` that *renames* a second prefix, but the result would again not be subtree-merge-able as that's a destructive change: [cont'd]

Comment: if you're importing such a renamed tree, and you have a file named `foo/bar`, *which prefix goes onto it?*

Comment: I've turned these two comments into a fairly major edit, with some additional thoughts on the reversal process for an extended version of `git subtree merge`, should one undertake to write an extended version of `git subtree split`.

Comment: That answer was a very thorough "no" :P. Thanks a lot for your answer, it made it much clearer to me how `git subtree` works.