# Split file into separate repository, preserving history

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-filter-branch

I want to do the equivalent of `git-subtree split` only on a single file rather than a directory.  That is, I want to make a new repository having only that one file and all its history.

Passing the filename to the `--prefix` argument does not work

```
git subtree split --prefix=file_name -b split
```

I tried a couple variations on `git-filter-branch` but did not find the correct incantation.

Comment: [See this related (but not quite the same) question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42661978/1256452). To achieve what you want, you must copy the commits you wish to copy, and not any of the others. You *can* do this with `git filter-branch`, it's just slow and painful. You can do it other ways that will be faster; until you write a script like `git subtree`, it will still be painful, though.

Comment: Here is a solution that works for one or more files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006679/1072626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter-branch` with a `tree-filter` deleting everything except the file you want to keep like

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find -type f -not -path ./foo/bar -delete' --prune-empty
```

Comment: Note that it is critical to include the `./` at the start of the file path.

Comment: I then used [this invocation of filter-branch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6149972/1072626) to drop the root commit.  In my case that file I wanted was not in the root commit but the commit was preserved as an empty commit.